# Find the first node with a specific attribute value

Tags: xpath

```
<document>
  <para>
    <heading id="1" type="new" level="1" />
    <span />
    <heading id="2" type="new" level="2" />
    <span />
  </para>
  <para>
    <heading id="3" type="new" level="1" />
    <span />
    <heading id="4" type="new" level="2" />
    <span />
  </para>
  <para>
    <heading id="5" type="old" level="2" />
    <span />
  </para>
  <para>
    <heading id="6" type="old" level="2" />
    <span />
  </para>
  <para>
    <heading id="7" type="old" level="2" />
    <span />
  </para>
  <para>
    <heading id="8" type="old" level="2" />
    <span />
  </para>
  <para>
    <span />
  </para>
</document>
```

Hello,

I'm parsing the above XML node-by-node in Javascript. Assuming that I'm currently at "heading id='8'" node, how would I look backwards and find the first node that has it's level set to "2" (same as the level on the node that I'm currently parsing) and type set to "new" using XPath expressions?

So, in the above exapmple, the element with id="4" must be selected.

Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm using XPath 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preceding` axis and use index to return only the nearest preceding element :

```
preceding::*[@level='2' and @type='new'][1]
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/ee3fec5c4e1fa821e26db7325623ac4f)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<heading id="4" level="2" type="new"/>
```

In the demo, I use `//*[@id='8']` to select element with `id=8` first, to simulate context element, and then continue selecting the target element using the above mentioned XPath.

Comment: Oops - corrected my question. It should be the level.

Comment: @Josh which one should be selected, element with id=2 or id=4?

Comment: Basically, I want to select the nearest one from the current node when looking backwards. So, in this case, it would be element with id=4.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I thought you wanted this.

> How would I look backwards and find the first node that has it's level set to the same as the level on **the node that I'm currently parsing** and type set to `new` using XPath expressions?

Oh well, leaving this here for future reference ...

```
[@type='new' and @level=current()/@level]
```